# get length of buffer using lower-level method on stack and heap

Tags: c++

Like following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define BUF_LEN_HEAP 32
#define BUF_LEN_STACK 64

int getBufLen(const char *buf)
{
    //...
}

void foo(const char *buf)
{
    int len = getBufLen(buf);
    //memcpy(new_buf, buf, len);
    //...
}

int main()
{
    char buf_stack[BUF_LEN_STACK];
    char *buf_heap = new char[BUF_LEN_HEAP];
    std::string str("abcdef");

    foo(buf_stack);
    foo(buf_heap);
    foo(str.c_str());

    delete [] buf_heap;

    return 0;
}
```

If get length of buffer very difficult pass argument to the functions.

Is there lower-level method to get length of buffer whatever the buffer allocated on stack or heap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to get the size of an array outside of the method that declared it, and only if the array was declared with a static length (known at compile time).

The usual way to handle this is to pass both a pointer and a size to any function writing to the buffer, just as `memcpy` does.

With c++ there's always the better option to use a `std::vector` instead of a plain array. The `std::vector` carries all needed information within one object that's easy to pass around.